# WCF Service (per-call) and Entity Framework Precompiled Queries in static function. Would that work?

Tags: .net, wcf, linq, entity-framework

If there is WCF service **(per-call)** which is using Entity Framework to access database, instead of directly using DLINQ, all the linq queries are pre-compiled (**as static member** of a class). Would that work, as WCF instance will be disposed after its call gets finished.

I could not find relevant question on SO. so please don't mind if i'm re-questioning.

[Reference of this topic can be found here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2007/06/25/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-2.aspx)

I am already familiar with WCF, LINQ. just not familiar with Pre-compiled queries and its impact on performance, even though a lot of people seems to claim it.

Comment: Where is the pre-compiled query stored currently? A static field would probably work fine.

Comment: yeah, a static member of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-compiled query is just preprocessed Linq statement. It doesn't have any internal state. All state including context instance is passed to the query as parameter so it can be static class member without any problem. If it is not static member you must keep it in some globally accessible object because the most significant performance cost of precompiled query is its compilation which should happen only once per application run.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question as 'static member', please note that i have also mentioned WCF Service to run in 'Per-Call' instance mode.

Comment: If this pre-compiled query is kept under state server, and state server can be on a different machine. i thin it would bring a negative impact on overall process performance.

Comment: Yes you mentioned Per-Call which in this case absolutely doesn't matter. What matters is if you create a new context instance in each WCF call because that context is passed to pre-compiled query. Pre-compiled query can be stored in any static field in your application. I don't understand your second comment and the meaning of state server - pre-compiled query must be inside your current application, it is not distributed. If you have multiple servers running the application each will have its own pre-compiled query.

Comment: what i meant in my 2nd comment is, if i store that pre-compiled query in cache (if its possible, or if it is serializable, i did not check it yet), and all cache is being maintained in different server (that's what i called state server!). Cut to the chase, i'm also thinking to change the WCF instance creation strategy in that case but that's totally a different debate.